# dev_install failed on ARM chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-os, portage

I'm trying this guide for having access to emerge on chromeos.

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/install-software-on-base-images

Unfortunately I always got the same error which is

```
$ sudo dev_install
Starting installation of developer packages.
First, we download the necessary files.
Downloading https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromeos-dev-installer/board/daisy/full-3.168.0.0/packages/app-misc/mime-types-8.tbz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127  100   127    0     0    252      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   305
[: 184: -ne: unexpected operator
Extracting /usr/local/portage/packages/app-misc/mime-types-8.tbz2
```

I think that it somehow returns a 404 everytime.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that commmondatastorage.googleapis.com doesn't handle non-existing stuff in standard way, so instead of returning code 404 when it cannot find the data it will return non-sensical XML document.

All that said your problem lies in incorrect binhost being used to download required packages. What I tried was this:

```
dev_install --binhost=https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromeos-prebuilt/board/daisy/full-15.11.12.140004/packages
```

Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue really since *that* binhost doesn't have python-2.6.8.tbz2 which is needed in later parts of installation. It's still a good start for investigation though I believe

Answer (score 1):

You are right: the file that it is trying to download does not exist.  You could try downloading it from somewhere else and saving it as /usr/local/portage/packages/app-misc/mime-types-8.tbz2; dev_install will probably not try to download it again.  If it does, you could try modifying the script (let me know if you need help with that).  Unfortunately, if you cannot find the file, there is not much that you can do until Google fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you maybe know where I can find this file ?

Comment: A quick Google search for "mime-types-8.tbz2" (with quotes) turns up a few, although they are not all identical.  If you are willing to trust them, try one at a time.  If one produces more errors later, it was probably not the right one.

Comment: So I've been investigating a bit more [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/gsNj5sGeIJI) but still I couldn't make this chromeos-dev build properly. So, to be continued...